# How to upload files from local drive to azure blob using webclient upload method

Tags: file-upload, ssis, azure, azure-storage, webclient.uploaddata

I want  to upload files from my local machine to windows azure containers using webclient upload method

```
UploadFile(Uri, String)
```

I dont want to use any cloud or azure api's to upload, reason being i am uploading files from Sql server integration services which does not support any cloud api's, so please can i know is their any way out upload the file to azure container

Answer (score 1):

Really, the only way to handle that would be to use a [SAS signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee395415.aspx).  You would need to send the client that needs to upload a valid SAS signature and then that client could just upload to that location.  Creating the SAS signature can be [done easily](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/uploading-windows-azure-blobs-from-silverlight-part-1-shared-access-signatures) using the Storage Client.